# Change IIS 6 Application pool without affecting Application Pools on entire server

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003, application-pool

I'm not sure if something odd is happening or if this is normal, but since framework 4 when I create a new site on our IISv6 install I used to get a message saying that changing to framework 4 would cause IIS to restart (but this has gone away since a few updates ago), I think it still restarts the server when I change the framework, just no warning any more. So I did a bit of investigation and wrote a script that allowed me to switch the framework version without doing that.

```
@Echo Off
set /p id=Enter Site Instance:
echo %id%
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -norestart -s W3SVC/%id%
pause
```

The problem I now have occurs when I change the app pool on any given web app; it appears to cause the other app pools (including the one I add to) to refresh.
I have sometimes had instances of a switch causing every app pool to stop, and then I have to restart them all again which can cause a bit of downtime. I have taken to only release new sites early in the morning or at the end of my work day, so as to avoid as much disruption as possible, but I dont see why something like this should be happening.

The setup I have is one app pool for test, one for live and one for the admin site, but when I change a site from test to live, it will causes all the app pools to become affected.

Can anyone tell me if this is something that always happened with previous versions of the framework and if there is a possible work around, for example can I script the app pool switch without affecting any of the other app pools

**Edit 2011-08-01**

found this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx, 
which mentions a script called `iisapp` and looks like it might do the job, will investigate more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer on this site: http://forums.iis.net/t/1152572.aspx

using a vbs in adminscripts called adsutil (not the `iisapp` as I thought...) you can write the following in a batch file.

```
@Echo Off
set /p id=Enter Site Name:
echo %id%
CD /D C:\inetpub\AdminScripts 
Cscript.exe /nologo adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/%id%/root/apppoolid [APP POOL NAME]
```